# How to use StringBuilder to process String in this Java program?

Tags: java, string, stringbuilder

Im having trouble figuring this problem out

Convert the sentence to a string in which the words are separated by spaces and only the first word starts with an uppercase letter. For example, the string “StopAndSmellTheRoses.” would be converted to “Stop and smell the roses.” Use StringBuilder object for processing the string. Use JOptionPane for user input/output. Use wrapper class Character for detecting words.

What I have so far. Im confused on how I use the wrapper class to detect uppercase letters and then insert a space behind them.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {


    String input;


    input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter a sentence in which "
            + "every word "
            + "begins with an upper case letter: ");

    input = input.trim();

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(input);

    for(int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++)
     {
        if((Character.isUpperCase(input)))
      {

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I know you dont like homework but maybe a hint?

Comment: There are plenty of rep-whores who will happily ruin your education by giving you an answer in exchange for a few points of reputation on this site. You shouldn't be asking for this type of help -- this is easy. If you can't do it you should learn how. Ask for help with specific syntax or things that are going wrong, not for us to do your work for you. That is lazy and intellectually dishonest.

Comment: I'll ask more focused questions next time

Comment: A few hints (as questions) to help you with your homework:  1)  Why start your output with a copy of the input?  2)  What type of input does `Character.isUpperCase` require?  3) What are you *giving* it as input?  4)  How can you find the *correct* input for that function?  (questions 2 - 4 can be answered by reading the documentation for the `Character` and `String` classes.  Read them carefully.)

Comment: I understand now that the Character wrapper class requires char as input. So you need to convert the string. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

So There is a easier way by using `regex` with [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
Arrays.toString("StopAndSmellTheRoses.".split("(?=[A-Z])"))
```

Comment: Not an answer to a "homework problem", but a quick easy solution for the _real-world_.

Comment: This also doesn't quite answer the question, since only the *first* word should start with an uppercase letter.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't actually tried running this but maybe something along these lines?

```
// Iterate up to second last element 
for(int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
    // Get i-th character
    char val = input.charAt(i);
    // If i-th character is upper case
    if((Character.isUpperCase(val))) {
        // Insert whitespace
        sb.append(" ");       
    }
    // Append lower case char
    sb.append(Character.toLowerCase(val));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Split then join.

```
String str = "StopAndSmellTheRoses.";
String[] r = str.split("(?=\\p{Upper})");
StringBuilder hello = new StringBuilder();
String delimiter = " "; 
for(String s : r) {
   hello.append(s).append(delimiter);
}
System.out.println(hello);
```

Output: `Stop And Smell The Roses.`